# insert update delete using ajax with codeignighter in php

Tags: ajax, insert

I am new in codeignighter

I am trying to build a php/mysql website using CI . But in the past, i didn't like the way php handled insert, update, delete, showing of entries. Ever since I have seen AJAX implemented beautifully on so many sites, i want to be able to do the same?

Comment: Did you try it yourself  ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont no insert, update, delete using ajax in codeignighter but i know the how to do insert update delete and select using jQuery ajax in php...may this will help you

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: $('#formcustomer').serialize(),
        type: 'post',           
        success: function (data) {

            });

});
```